# Where do scheduled python programs "print"?

Tags: python, cron

If I schedule `print "Hello World!";` to run every hour with crontab, where will Hello World! be printed? Is there a log file?
If I do it with Java or C instead of Python, will it make any difference?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They will be sent to the email address defined at the top of the crontab, or to the crontab's owner by default. See the `crontab(5)` man page for more details.